# Hide a button in SSRS pdf view but show in online view

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a button in the SSRS report Report1. This buttons opens other report called DetailReport. In online view of the report for faster rendering the button on report1 opens the DetailReport. But when on pdf view the Button appears on the report, which is of no use.

I have found way to hide and show the entire page by passing parameter.

Using code for visiblity as :

```
=IIF(Parameters!ShowDetaiReport.Value=true,false,true)
```

But the button is shown or hidden both online and in pdf.

Is there any way to show button in the online view but hide it when I download pdf or word. Can i replace the Button with report itself when I download it.

FYI: I am using SSRS 2012

Answer (score 7):

You can check to see what type of report is being rendered using the `Globals!RenderFormat` Built-in Field.  You can either use `.Name` to check for a specific render format - such as `PDF` or `Excel` - or you can simply use `.IsInteractive` to check if the user can actually click things.

You can apply this check in the Button's `Visibility` -> `Show or hide based on an expression` property value as follows: `=iif(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive, False, True)`

If you want to test this without exporting your reports, you can preview in `Print Layout`, which isn't interactive.